# Can not push to the SVN repo using git svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm going to push new changes to the SVN repo, which was not modified after the last `git svn dcommit`. I have 4 commits on top in my local version since the last push to the repo. And now I'm always getting this error, when trying to do `git svn dcommit` again:

```
ERROR from SVN:
Connection reset by peer: Can't read from connection: Connection reset by peer
W: 30d2c8bdab2d4cdd860b6ba1b45db55967232d1c and refs/remotes/git-svn differ, using rebase:
:040000 040000 bcb0b926dcd6608b8f243578e44ff0ab32457e32 2040ef070e43df814825c9a9c7708741a3395c9a M  android
:040000 040000 d453457cac2fd97f7ff92bfa849f73edb19ab41d 5b8dd84f1bcf9d136cd410c238750965b3615787 M  ios
Current branch svn-3 is up to date.
ERROR: Not all changes have been committed into SVN, however the committed
ones (if any) seem to be successfully integrated into the working tree.
Please see the above messages for details.
```

There are no any messages about conflicts. `git svn rebase` returns:

```
Current branch svn-3 is up to date.
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could fix this strange bug using next steps:

1. `git reset --soft refs/remotes/git-svn` to return local repo's state to the last successful commit which was updated to the remote SVN repo.
2. Looking in `git reflog show` we can find the last working commit (its hash) with actual changes and apply them again using `git checkout` and then commit them again.

After that I was able to do `git svn dcommit` successfully without any errors.